# I want to automate IT tasks and wonder if Python is a good choice

Tags: windows-7, windows, python, automation

I am a beginner in programming, mainly toying around with Python and Java at the moment. I want to get a little further and many suggestions reasonably encourage finding ways to implement the language into tasks you already do.

I'm an IT person, and starting my own IT company, and I decided it would be a good idea to write scripts for automating several common tasks I do. The first one I am looking at is automating the installation of Windows Updates on a fresh install (if OS version matters, let's focus on Windows 7).

My curiosity - is Python good for such a task? Do I need to install Python on every computer I would want to run these automation scripts on in order to use them? Is there a better language for writing such scripts? (Better being requiring less set up to be functional, not needing extras installed, etc) These scripts would be run on customer computers, so I don't want to have to add a lot to their systems in order to make it functional.

I am a newbie when it comes to programming, so I may be running off of some false premises but any assistance in this regards would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't address the question, directly as it is worded because it is very much opinion based and off topic. But a few things to consider when deciding if its a good platform.

What level of portability do you need? If you are going to use it on many machines you need either a compiled Python Script (No more editing) or Python on all machines.

Installing Python on all machines is not an option, most likely. As it only introduces a system that can break, and most enterprises won't want to worry about supporting a platform that Windows has a built in equivalent for. PowerShell is worth looking into, while on the topic.

If you are starting an IT company, you should really expect foremost not to change the companies you support and their underlying setup without a very good reason. You not knowing Windows shop standards is not a very good reason, if you expect to be respected as the "expert".

Also, Java is a bad choice. Why use Java if interoperability is not a primary concern? .NET is more stable, less of a headache for support and every bit as friendly for scripting (PowerShell, VB.NET, C#).

Comment: Sorry, I figured my question was potentially misleading. First, I don't plan on using Java, just noting that I have some minor experience in it. Secondly, the scripts would be for my personal use and not for the company I currently work for. I want to eventually use them for my own small business after thorough testing, of course. I've been reading on VBS as an option, too. Basically, in my hypothetical scenerio, I want to be able to launch my script on a brand new system and walk away as it does the work tasked to it.

Comment: Outside the Q&A format, I would use PowerShell. VBS is OK, but really not the modern standard. And you can do literally anything with it, want to use commands from the DOS days, supported. Want a full language syntax, done. Want to use the full power of .NET in a script, supported. Python isn't a bad choice, but it is a distant 2nd at best compared to PS IMO.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the input. I'll look into PowerShell and see where I get. I appreciate the help on an admittedly opinion-based question (quickly learning those are taboo on this site).

Comment: One last thing, can you run a PowerShell script on a computer that doesn't have PS installed?

Comment: @user295401 Vista and up has PowerShell installed out of the box. Slightly different version between NT6 to 6.2 (Windows 8, Server 2012).